# Применение ::after к placeholder в Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

Есть поле типа текст для элемента `input`. К этому полю требуется применить `placeholder`. Все бы ничего, но еще есть одно условие. Нужно сделать в конце текста `placeholder`'a красную звездочку (сноска типа "обязательное поле для заполнения").

Для этого использую псевдоэлемент `::after`:

```
#myy .t3::-webkit-input-placeholder::after {
    content: '*';
   color: red;
}

#myy .t3:-moz-placeholder::after {
    content: '*';
   color: red;  
}

#myy .t3::-moz-placeholder::after {  /* Firefox 19+ */
    content: '*';
   color: red;  
}

#myy .t3:-ms-input-placeholder::after {  
    content: '*';
   color: red;  
}
```

В хроме работает. А вот в Firefox нет. Может, я что-то не так делаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего это связано с тем, что `:before` и `:after` добавляет контент к содержимому элемента, а у input содержимого нет.

Это не кроссбраузерное решение.

Ваш вариант:

1. Работает - `Opera 29.0.1795.60`, `Chrome Версия 43.0.2357.81 m`
2. Не работает - `FF 38.0.5`, `IE10`, `IE9`, `Safari`

**Example 1**

```js
$('#text').focus(function() {
    $('#redstar').hide();
});

$('#text').blur(function() {
    if ($(this).val().trim() === '') {
        $('#redstar').show();
    }
});
```

```css
input {
    width: 200px;
}

label {
    z-index: 100;
    position: relative;
    left: -200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text"/>
<label for="text" id="redstar">Some text<span style="color: red">*</span></label>
```

**Example 2**

```css
div {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
div > input{
    height: 30px;
    padding: 5px 15px;
}
div > label {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0.5em;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -0.5em;    
}
div > input[type=text]:focus + label {
    display: none;
}
div > label > span {
    letter-spacing: -2px;
     color: #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.redstar {
    color: #f00;
    font-size: 18px;    
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input id="nameid" type="text" />
    <label for="nameid"> 
        <span>Some text</span>  
        <span class="redstar">*</span>        
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Плохой способ. Хотя бы pointer-events:none добавь. Переход в поле - это не обязательно клик.

Comment: А где я написал, что это самый лучший вариант? Напишие свой альтернативный вариант, который будет лучше моего.

Comment: Я предложил добавить ещё одно css-свойство, чтобы он стал лучше ;)

Comment: Спасибо, буду использовать вариант с `label`'ом.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете скрипт, совершенно не обязательно вставлять красную звездочку в плейсхолдер. Это может быть и обычный строчный элемент, выводимый рядом с инпутом, который благодаря абсолютному позиционированию будет смещен и выведен в правом краю инпута. Важна же визуализация, а не разрыв пятой точки.

Другое дело, если требуется показать что это обязательное поле, тогда лучше вывести бордер определенного цвета, проверяющий содержимое до отправки. Валидация проще говоря, ее никто не запрещает. Как не запрещают и общаться с заказчиком, либо дизайнером проекта, чтобы скорректировать элемент в плане юзабилити.

Лейблы вещь занятная, но отнимает много места на небольших экранах. Учитывайте это.